# Rails - Acts_as_Taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable

Anyone here have experience with the Rails Acts as Taggable plugin?
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/

I'm curious to know the following: Can you keep tags silod? My app has projects, and I'd like the tags to be defined at the project level.

So in a project if you tag something as "CUSTOMER" or "PR" you only see those tags as options in that project. As seeing someone elses tags in another project would be disturbing.

Anything like that possible?

Comment: Did you mean "solid" instead of "silod"?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a n-n relationship between projects and users? Just an idea, but you could implement acts-as-taggable on the linking model (Project -> ProjectUser [acts-as-taggable] -> User). Then each user would have different tags on their project.

Comment: interesting. Not sure I need dif tags per user ,just per project

Comment: `As seeing someone elses tags in another project would be disturbing' - that means to me different tags per user per project, if you only need tags per project, just make the project-model taggable.